# how to open instagram user profile in native app

Tags: android, profile, instagram

Are there anyway to open the instagram user profile like http://instagram.com/username by intent in native app, we should not link to instagram by default brouser.

```
 intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/username"));
```

Comment: Have you tried integrating WebView for this purpose.

Answer (score -1):

there is a command-line approach. You can use *am* command to get the browser to navigate to a given web:

am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d http://instagram.com/username

Comment: This opens a web browser, not the Instagram App. Also, you should always use intents over command line in a published app.